# SQL Join but return rows based on criteria or order of preference

Tags: sql, select, join, subquery, correlated-subquery

Using Microsoft SQL Server I am joining two tables. A row from Table 1 relates to potentially a few rows in Table 2. I want to ideally bring back just one row from Table 2 based on what data is present and certain criteria

Table 2 has an ID, which is joined on, and a datetime field.
I've been only bringing back values where the datetime is NULL but although they are valid it unnecessarily excludes when the datetime is still in the future.

I would like to be able to bring back one row from Table 2 where if the datetime field is in the future that row has precedence over a row with a NULL value. If there is no joined row with a datetime in the future it will return the NULL value row

I think I need some form of sub query or something that grades the rows present and brings back the highest values but I'm not sure.

Whatever the method for doing this their are a number of similar situations in this query where this logic would be used.

Answer (score 1):

If i got you correct, you want to get rows from Table2 where the datetime field is null or has a value in the future. You said you want the date in the future to have precedence over the NULL value, so i understand that you want kind of a maximum value. Let's set some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (id_table1 int not null primary key)

INSERT INTO Table1 (id_table1)
VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO Table1 (id_table1)
VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO Table1 (id_table1)
VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO Table1 (id_table1)
VALUES (4)
INSERT INTO Table1 (id_table1)
VALUES (5)


CREATE TABLE Table2 (id_table2 int not null primary key, id_table1 int, date_value datetime)

INSERT INTO Table2 (id_table2,id_table1,date_value)
VALUES (1,1,'2001-01-01 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO Table2 (id_table2,id_table1,date_value)
VALUES (2,1,NULL)
INSERT INTO Table2 (id_table2,id_table1,date_value)
VALUES (3,1,'2015-01-01 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO Table2 (id_table2,id_table1,date_value)
VALUES (4,2, '2002-01-01 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO Table2 (id_table2,id_table1,date_value)
VALUES (5,3, '2003-01-01 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO Table2 (id_table2,id_table1,date_value)
VALUES (6,3, '2018-01-01 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO Table2 (id_table2,id_table1,date_value)
VALUES (7,4, '2004-01-01 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO Table2 (id_table2,id_table1,date_value)
VALUES (8,4,NULL)
```

Now you have 0..n rows in Table2 for each id_table1.

As a start you can get all rows from Table2 which match the criteria NULL or in the future:

```
declare @datThreshold datetime
set @datThreshold=getdate()

SELECT *
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE t2.date_value is null OR t2.date_value>@datThreshold
```

As i said, i understand that you want a maximum value for the remaining dates where NULL is the lowest. You can achieve that by setting the NULL values to a default, which can be @datThreshold because this will be the lowest value due to the WHERE condition.

```
declare @datThreshold datetime
set @datThreshold=getdate()

SELECT id_table1, max(isnull(t2.date_value,@datThreshold)) max_date
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE t2.date_value is null OR t2.date_value>@datThreshold
GROUP BY t2.id_table1
```

Now you have one row for each id_table1 and have to join it to Table1:

```
declare @datThreshold datetime
set @datThreshold=getdate()

SELECT t1.id_table1,max.id_table1,max.max_date
FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN (SELECT id_table1, max(isnull(t2.date_value,@datThreshold)) max_date
        FROM Table2 t2
        WHERE t2.date_value is null OR t2.date_value>@datThreshold
        GROUP BY t2.id_table1) max ON t1.id_table1=max.id_table1
```

You can also replace the default date by NULL again:

```
declare @datThreshold datetime
set @datThreshold=getdate()

SELECT t1.id_table1,max.id_table1,case max.max_date when @datThreshold then NULL else max.max_date end date_value
FROM Table1 t1
    JOIN (SELECT id_table1, max(isnull(t2.date_value,@datThreshold)) max_date
        FROM Table2 t2
        WHERE t2.date_value is null OR t2.date_value>@datThreshold
        GROUP BY t2.id_table1) max ON t1.id_table1=max.id_table1
```